# How to share libraries across web components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, custom-element

I've started a micro frontends project by utilizing custom elements.
I'm looking for a way to share dependencies between all of the parts of the application.

I'm wondering how I could do this with Material-ui library.
For example one could attach library to the window object and access it from inside of the custom element (web component).

The problem that I'm seeing here is that the material-ui exists as a npm module, and I haven't managed to find an option to load it via `script` tag.

The custom elements are loaded via 
`http import` [image] 
which means that they will be loaded before the `window` object has been populated with the `material-ui` library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found one way of sharing libraries, for example UI libraries, such as Material-UI, and that is by putting them on a global scope (`window` object).

Then the `web component` (`custom element`) which is being included in the composition layer can read it from the window object inherited from the context in which it's included.

This approach can be easily used in case when there is only functionality needed. In case of UI library, where there is style as well, one has to pay attention if the shadow dom is turned on or not on the web component, and turn it off if it is.

Reason for this is the web component's shadow dom styles scoping capability, meaning one can simply inherit styles from a parent.

Here's a quick sample that I've made last year and now I've just made it work again :) [github.com/mnemanja/web-components-composition](http://github.com/mnemanja/web-components-composition)

Comment: Do you have a sample for this approach? I am trying to solve the same problem.

Comment: Hi Umar,
The solution that I've ended up developing was requiring that the same libraries get used across different parts of the application (web components). 

The host app would be "publishing" all shared libraries on the `window` object, where the web component could find it. Then the component would consume it from there (for web component development I've had a local version as well being loaded conditionally).

Comment: Thanks Nemanja. I want to know how you "publish the shared libraries to the `window` object". Can you provide a code sample or a link to one?

Comment: No problem @UmarFarooqKhawaja, I'm actually preparing an example for you. I hope to have it ready at the beginning of the next week.

In that example, I'm assigning, for example, material-ui library to the `window` object.
e.g.
`window.mui = materialUi`

Comment: That is superkind of you, Nemanja. It would be very helpful. Brilliant. Looking forward to that.

Comment: Here's a quick sample that I've made last year and now I've just made it work again :)
https://github.com/mnemanja/web-components-composition

There isn't much documentation there at the moment. Feel free to ask questions there and I'll get back asap.